# Powershell script for downloading files going corrupt

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I am trying something very simple. Downloading a file and moving it to a specific folder. With this script it downloads the files and moves it correctly, but all the files I download this way are corrupt. What am I doing wrong? I've tried different source urls, these didnt make a difference.

```
# Source URL
$url = "https://easyupload.io/wbpkvq" 
# Destation file
$dest = "D:\Temp\trololol.mp3"
# Download the file
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -OutFile $dest
```

Comment: This is an URL that lead to a page. You're not saving a MP3. You're saving html. Nothing is going corrupt. You are saving a webpage as a mp3 and then try to open it as such. It cannot work.

Comment: Use `$response = Invoke-WebRequest` and inspect the returned object properties. I think it is storing a web page, not the MP3 file.

Answer (score 0):

This website prevents 'abuses' of the type you're trying to do: automated downloads. You could try something like AHK or Selenium if you really want to automate a single click. But those solutions tend to rot quickly.